# Geoserver; Expecting at least 50.000 users on my WebApp in one weekend. How to prepare?

Tags: postgresql, leaflet, mapbox, openlayers-3, geoserver

My webapplication consists of an interactive (mapbox / openlayers3 / leaflet) map, which displays points. The webapplication will have two functionalities:

- A view that displays real-time data
- A view that can be filtered on specific attributes

The most traffic on this webapplication will be about 42 requests every 30 seconds. In response to this the server will respond depending on whether the request is WMS or WFS. In the case of WFS it will send about 800 small (+/- 5 columns inc. lat/lng) features on each request. In the case of WMS it will render maptiles based on max 150.000 points with a custom SLD. I want to realize the features listed above and ensure optimal performance of the application. The data is hosted on a remote postgress db, Geoserver will provide WMS / WFS services to send the images / data to the client.

I was planning to use a WFS-service for the first view, since it's only visualizing real-time data. Which means that the application will check the remote db every 30 seconds for changes, if there are new points in the database these will be displayed. I figured a WFS would cause less load on the server since it doesn't have to render images. Every 30 seconds there will be 40 new points tops. In order to check for new features, I want to perform a getFeature with maxFeature='1' from the client, and check the total key which is send by the server.

For the view that will display filtered data I want to use a WMS-service since it will probably display +/- 150.000 points per request. So I figured a WMS would be better performing, I don't know if using geowebcache is an option since the dataset will be changing constantly. Also I want to use a custom SLD to generate a heatmap of the points, so I will not be displaying the actual points. Example of the heatmap SLD -> user30184's respose to this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102563/heat-map-density-map-from-dynamic-points-table-in-mapserver-geoserver question.

What would be the bottlenecks in my solution, the remote db server, Geoserver, or both? What kind of specs would my server need to handle this properly?

Comment: It just came to my mind that I could use a plugin to generate the heatmap clientside to reduce load on the server.